# How to set Capistrano's copy_exclude to exclude all .svn folders

Tags: capistrano

In Capistrano, how can I set `copy_exclude` so that all `.svn` folders (recursively) will not be copied and deployed?

NOTE: I'm not using `svn:export/checkout`. I'm using Capistrano to copy a local SVN checkout to deploy it to the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Ant-style recursive syntax](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html) like this: `**/.svn`