# Capifony: How to remove all .svn directories when deploying via copy?

Tags: capifony

I would like to add a post deployment command for Capifony to delete all the .svn directories after a fresh deployment but I can't find any examples or documentation. How is this done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set Capistrano's copy\_exclude to exclude all .svn folders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12848456/how-to-set-capistranos-copy-exclude-to-exclude-all-svn-folders)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `deploy.rb` file:

```
set :copy_exclude, ".svn/*"
```

Comment: I will rather use `set :copy_exclude, [".svn", "**/.svn"]`

Comment: j0k, thank you. Your solution is correct for completely excluding the .svn directories.